# Detect and Remove Outliers as step of a Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, classification

I have a problem, I'm trying to build my own class to put into a pipeline in python, but it doesn't work.

The problem I am trying to solve is a multiclass classification problem.

What I want to do this to add a step in the pipeline to detect and remove outliers.
I found this [detect and remove outliers in pipeline python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346725/can-i-add-outlier-detection-and-removal-to-scikit-learn-pipeline) which is very similar to what I did.
This is my class:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np

class OutlierExtraction(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs ):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def transform(self, X, y):
        """
            X should be of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            y should be of shape (n_samples,)
        """

        lof = LocalOutlierFactor(**self.kwargs)
        lof.fit(X)
        nof = lof.negative_outlier_factor_
        return X[nof > np.quantile(nof, 0.95), :], y[nof > np.quantile(nof, 0.95)]

    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self
```

But i get this error `in fit_transform return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X) TypeError: transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

The following code is the code i use to call this class:

```
scaler = preprocessing.RobustScaler()
outlierExtractor = OutlierExtraction()
pca = PCA()
classfier = svm.SVC()

pipeline = [('scaler', scaler),
            ('outliers', outlierExtractor),
        ('reduce_dim', pca),
        ('classfier', classfier)]

pipe = Pipeline(pipeline)

params = {
    'reduce_dim__n_components': [5, 15],
    'classfier__kernel': ['rbf'],
    'classfier__gamma': [0.1],
    'classfier__C': [1],
    'classfier__decision_function_shape':['ovo']}

my_scoring = 'f1_macro'
n_folds = 5
gscv = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=params, scoring=my_scoring, n_jobs=-1, cv=n_folds, refit=True)
gscv.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because the transform method `def transform(self, X, y)` requires *both* `X` and `y` to be passed in, but whatever is calling it is only passing `X`. (I can't see where it's called from in your code so assume it's being called by the underlying library).

I don't know if making `y` optional (`def transform(self, X, y=None)` and modifying your method would work in this case. Otherwise, you'll have to figure out how to get the calling code to pass `y`, or provide it another way.

I'm not familiar with the library, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e/sklearn/base.py#L688-L693) shows that `transform()` should only take a single parameter `X`:

```
        if y is None:
            # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
            return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
        else:
            # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
            return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
```

Comment: making y optional rise an error, but I understand the error, thank you

Answer (score 4):

@TimCroydon has it right: `sklearn` currently assumes that transformers only transform their independent variables.  There have been some long discussions on how best to relax this:

- [SLEP 001](https://scikit-learn-enhancement-proposals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/slep001/proposal.html) (!)
- [PR 13269](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/13269), a proof-of-concept toward that
- [Issue 3855](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3855)

The `scikit-learn-contrib` package `imbalanced-learn` supports a number of resamplers, which have similar effect but different context; you may be able to use that, but perhaps it will look a little weird to be `fit_sample`ing when removing outliers.  Anyway, they have a custom version of `Pipeline` that deals with that resampling elegantly.

Finally, you *may* be able to just override the `fit_transform` method in your custom class.  It seems like it should work for this situation, though it may cause issues elsewhere.