# how do i get my Grid Search CV with SVC to work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, svm

I would like to perform the steps I wrote in the pipeline but it gives me the following error:

```
All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 
'passthrough' 'IsolationForest ()' (type <class 'sklearn.ensemble._iforest.IsolationForest'>)
 doesn't
```

my code is as follows:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
             ('scaling', None),
             ('anomaly', IsolationForest() ),
             ('balancing',None),
             ('classificator', SVC())
           ])

params = {'scaling': [StandardScaler(), RobustScaler(), MinMaxScaler()],
      'balancing':[RandomUnderSampler(),SMOTE()], 'balancing__random_state':45, 'balancing__k_neighbors':[3, 5, 7, 10],
      'classificator__C': np.logspace(-2,1,4)}
     

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid = params)
gs.fit(x_tr, y_tr)
```

Comment: Point is that `IsolationForest` is not a transformer, namely its class does not implement `.fit_transform()`; it is an estimator, it only implements `.fit()`. As the error says you can't use it in an intermediate step of a `Pipeline`, but only in the final step. Indeed, when calling method `.fit()` on a `Pipeline` instance (which does happen in your `gs.fit(x_tr, y_tr)`) `.fit_transform()` is called sequentially on all transformers in the pipeline so that each transformed output is passed to the next transformer until reaching the final estimator on which `.fit()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in the comments, `IsolationForest` has no `transform()` method indeed. However, you can likely write a transforming wrapper thyself (see the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346725/can-i-add-outlier-detection-and-removal-to-scikit-learn-pipeline)). You'd likely have to resort to using imblearn pipeline however, otherwise the features and target length could mismatch.